# EF Core 3 unable to translate query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I know EF Core 3 cannot translate `GroupJoin` in LINQ lambda that's why I have used LINQ query syntax but still not sure why it's unable to translate.

EF Core 3 is unable to translate the following query:

```
await using var context= this.contextFactory.Create();

var underwritingDivisionHierarchyQuery = context.Submissions_UnderwritingDivisionHierarchies
    .Select(x => new {
        x.Id,
        name = $"{x.SubmissionsParent.Name}-{x.Submissionschild.Name}",
        x.Active 
});

var hasErrors = await (from stagedData in context.API_Risks

    join underwritingDivisionHierarchy in underwritingoivisionHierarchyQuery on stagedData.UnderwritingDivision equals underwritingDivisionHierarchy.Name into underwritingDivisionHierarchies
    from underwritingDivisionHierarchy in underwritingDivisionHierarchies.DefaultIfEmpty()

    where stagedData.OperationId = 1 && stagedData.ProgramReference != null & (underwritingDivisionHierarchy == null || !underwritingDivisionHierarchy.Active)
    select stagedData.UnderwritingDivision)
.AnyAsync()
.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Just because EF core can't. It's an annoying limitation.

Comment: But what can I do to sort this out? @GertArnold

Comment: Please search the internet for the exception you get. This is a well-known stumbling block and there are many work-arounds.

Comment: Where is exception? Which part is not translatable?

Comment: Also, just in case, consider using string concatenation instead of string interpolation, e.g. `name = x.SubmissionsParent.Name + "-" + x.Submissionschild.Name`